# Couldn't lock the download directory in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, virtual-machine

while installing lynx on Ubuntu using this command

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
```

i get this error

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the download directory (/var/lib/cache/dpkg/)
```

how to resolve this problem ???

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any process, update etc, trying go gain the lock?
To remove any existing locks, please use this commands in your temrinal:

```
sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: After running these command now if i use   -italic_ **sudo apt-get install lynx**

Comment: When I ran this command, my screen went blank and all program exited.  Nothing would get it to respond, so I had to restart.  Not going to downvote, since it apparently fixed @Rdx's problem, but be warned.